# How do I create a directory to assign values to similar items in a list.

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary where I can assign a value that classifies the same object in the list. Note that I don't have a preexisting value, I want python to assign one. Here is what I have:

```
 In [38]: post_title_list
 Out[38]: [u'the rfe master list',
           u'the rfe master list',
           u'the rfe master list', 
           ...]
```

the rfe master list goes on for about 700 more times until we begin the next title which is u'the co problem'.  I want to assign one number for each new phrase in the list, so the rfe master list is assigned 1 until we get to the co problem which would be assigned 2 and so on.

I have tried the following codes with no luck:

```
  In [39]: d = dict(zip(post_title_list, range(len(post_title_list)))  
  Out[39]: {u'the rfe master list': '491818'}

  In [40]: {item: str(i) for i, item in enumerate(post_title_list)}
  Out[40]: {u'the rfe master list': '491818'}

  In [41]: dict.fromkeys(post_title_list)
  Out[41]: {u'the rfe master list': None}
```

Desired output:

```
  Out[42]:  {u'the rfe master list': 1,
             u'the rfe master list': 1,
             u'the rfe master list': 1,
             u'the co problem'     : 2,
             u'the co problem'     : 2,
             u'expecting delays'   : 3,
             u'denied help         : 4,
             ...}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you cant have same multiple keys. You can only have one `"the rfe master list"`, not multiple, if you add another, it will replace the old one.

Comment: keys cannot be similar in a python `dict` whereas you can have similar values for different keys.

Comment: Each key in a dictionary must be unique, so your goal of having duplicate entries is not possible. You could create a list of value/number pairs like [('master list', 1)] instead if you really need duplicates.

Comment: as @Sohier Dane said you could have list of tuples like : `[(u'the rfe master list', 1), (u'the rfe master list', 1), (u'the rfe master list', 1), (u'the co problem', 2), (u'expecting delays', 3), (u'denied help', 4)]` as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, dictionaries need to have unique keys. So I would suggest a list of tuples.
To generate a similar form of the desired output, I suggest something like:

```
ctr = 1

l = [
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'b',
    'b',
    'b',
    'b',
    'b',
    'b',
    'c',
    'c',
    'c',
    'c',
    'c',
]

out = []
for idx, element in enumerate(l):
    if idx == 0:
        out.append((element, ctr))
    else:
        if element != l[idx-1]:
            ctr = ctr + 1
        out.append((element, ctr))

print(out)
```

giving

```
[('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3)]
```

---

*Update due to comment*

The way lists are printed depends on which development environment you're using. However, to have something IDE-independent, this should to the job:

```
for t in out:
    print(t)
```

Comment: this works nicely, but when I print the list out, it looks like this:
[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a',1)...]     

how can I make sure it looks like your print out (aka vertical) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out in the comments to your question, you can't have multiple entries for the same key in a dictionary.

One way to go would be a dictionary in which every title occurs only once and maps to the corresponding number:

```
d = {}
next_id = 1
for title in post_title_list:
    if title not in d:
        d[title] = next_id
        next_id += 1
```

Alternatively, you can create a list with a tuple `(title,id)`for every element in your list:

```
l = []
next_id = 0
last = None
for title in post_title_list:
    if title != last:
        next_id += 1
    l.append((title,next_id))
    last = title
```

Comment: this works nicely, but when I print the list out, it looks like this: [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('a',1)...] how can I make sure it looks like your print out (aka vertical) Thanks!